# Embed a image to eclipse and display it with scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to ask how to display an image and how to embed it on eclipse.

after embedding it i am trying to display it as

```
<img src=("/UbitMvc/riivo.jpg")/>
<img src="/UbitMvc/1.jpg">
<img src="/home/ilgun/play/UbitProject/Resources/1.jpg">
```

so basically i'm trying every possible way. What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I believe you need to be way more specific with your question.

Comment: Are you asking how to add an image to your scala.html files from your directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for Play! 2.0 and above, yu'll need to add a GET to your /conf/routes file in order to be able to access your images.

```
GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Also I believe that the standard for Play! applications is to drop all images, javascripts, and stylesheets into their appropriate folder within the /public directory.

ex. /public/images/riivo.jpg

So your img call should end up being

```
<img src=@routes.Assets.at("/images/riivo.jpg")>
```

Comment: Latest accepted answer I've ever gotten, but 16 months late is better than never!